# return 1 when multiple conditions meet

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case, window-functions, snowflake-schema

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ACCOUNT       hour_count
A             24
B             24
C             23
D             22
```

I want to create an sql statement that just returns "1" when ALL conditions meet:

```
when account is A, hour_count = 24
when account is B, hour_count = 24
when account is C, hour_count > 22
when account is D, hour_count > 22
```

How can I achieve this?

I tried using a CASE statement, but i couldn
if 't figure out how to include multiple conditions. It wouldn't work with an AND within a single WHEN statement:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN ((ACCOUNT = 'A' AND hour_count = 24) )
    THEN 1
END
FROM hour_counts
```

Comment: It should work that way. What was your error?

Comment: What if one or more of the accounts (A,B,C,D) are missing but the ones available satisfy the condition?

Comment: @Rajat I guess then their value is unknown (NULL) and NULL is an absorbing element in relation algebra

Comment: @LajosArpad Sorry, I meant those accounts not being present in the data rather than having null values

Comment: @Rajat can you show your full query, including the where? Also, I would suggest an `ELSE NULL` in the case-when block.

Comment: @LajosArpad I didn't ask the question

Comment: @Rajat right, please excuse me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only a single 1 returned if all of the conditions met else nothing returned

```sql
with cte as (
select case
          when account in (‘A’,’B’) and hour_count = 24) then 1 
          when account in (‘C’,’D’) and hour_count > 22) then 1
       end as c_count
  from hour_count)
select 1 as one       
  from cte
having sum(c_count)=4 —- if all conditions met
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn each check into an exists predicate in a where clause:

(Optional sample test data):

```
create or replace table T1 as 
select 
COLUMN1::string as "ACCOUNT",
COLUMN2::float as "HOUR_COUNT"
from (values
('A',24),
('B',24),
('C',23),
('D',22)
);
```

Query with exists predicates for each check:

```
select 1 as CHECKS where
exists (select 1 from T1 where ACCOUNT = 'A' and HOUR_COUNT = 24) and
exists (select 1 from T1 where ACCOUNT = 'B' and HOUR_COUNT = 24) and
exists (select 1 from T1 where ACCOUNT = 'C' and HOUR_COUNT > 22) and
exists (select 1 from T1 where ACCOUNT = 'D' and HOUR_COUNT > 22)
;
```

Note that with the test data this will not return a row. That's because it fails on the check for account D. You can change the check to >= or change the value for D to see the effect of passing the exists checks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need it to return 1 or 0, it gets easier

```
select iff(count(distinct account)=4,1,0) 
from t
where (account in ('A','B') and hour_count = 24) or 
      (account in ('C','D') and hour_count > 22)
```